# Ensure item is purchased before allowing to download from my server when download is invoked later after purchasing

Tags: android, security, webserver, signature, in-app-purchase

I have the following scenario:

1. I have some items that I want to sell
2. User buys the item and it is marked is "Purchased". Now user can download the file.
3. User presses "Download" button and downloads the file (it must be some unique link)

I read all inapp billing docs and steps 1 and 2 work fine for me. How can I implement step 3 on the android side?

I imagine this something like:

1. App sends product id to my server
2. My server responds with a nonce
3. I send this nonce and product id to Google Play
4. Google Play returns me a signed ticket (nonce and product id)
5. I send this signed ticket to my server
6. my server returns file for app

At this moment I can only handle info if purchase status is changed, but what if I first buy the item and then later download it securely.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? I am not 100% sure what you are asking. Are you asking how the user can trigger a download? Or are you asking if the user can download the file at a later point in time after the purchase?

Comment: I am asking if the user can download the file at a later point in time after the purchase.

Comment: @Solvek did you solve your problem? i want to implement same architecture as you describe in your question.help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

The user can definitely download the file at a later point in time. There are two ways to approach this:

**Managed Purchases**

A managed purchase is a one-time in-app billing purchase. These kinds of purchases would be for things like permanent access to content or permanent upgrades to an app (think "pro" versions). If your purchase is a managed purchase (which means the Google servers always know about the purchase) then you can follow your steps 1-6 at any point in time, allowing the user to download the file at their convenience.

**Unmanaged Purchases**

An unmanaged purchase is for things like video game money, where you want the user to be able to make the purchase multiple times. Unmanaged purchases need to be handled by your servers and cannot involve Google Services after the transaction has been completed. In this case, you register the purchase with your server, and then afterwards you can allow the user to download the file at any point in time simply by authenticating them with your server.

Let me know if you have any additional questions and I would be happy to help.